# Is the circle the ellipse with minimal perimeter?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analysis

Consider a family of ellipses parametrized as $(a \cos t, a^{-1} \sin t)$, $a\in (0,\infty)$ and $t\in(0,2\pi]$, such that them all have the same area, $\pi$.

I wish to prove that (only) the circle has the minimal perimeter. So considering the function

\begin{align}
P(a)=\int _0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t+a^{-2}\cos^2t}\:dt
\end{align}

how can one prove that

\begin{align}
P'(a)=\int _0^{2\pi}\frac{a\sin^2 t-a^{-3}\cos^2t}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 t+a^{-2}\cos^2t}}\:dt
\end{align}

vanishes **only** for $a=1$ ?

Comment: There are typos. The power $-1$ has to be $-2.$

Comment: $\displaystyle\operatorname{P}\left(a\right) = {4\operatorname{E}\left(1 - a^{4}\right) \over a}$ where $\displaystyle\operatorname{E}$ is the $Complete\ Elliptic\ Integral$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite $P'(a)$ as ${2\over a^2}f(a)$, where:
$$
f(a)=\int_0^\pi{a^4\sin^2t-\cos^2t\over
\sqrt{a^4\sin^2t+\cos^2t}}dt.
$$
We then have:
$$
f'(a)=\int_0^\pi{\frac{2 a^3 \sin ^2(t) \left(a^4 \sin ^2(t)+
3 \cos ^2(t)\right)}{\left(a^4 \sin^2(t)
+\cos ^2(t)\right)^{3/2}}}dt>0.
$$

Hence $f(a)$ is increasing and vanishes only for $a=1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\operatorname{f}'\left(\,{a}\,\right) < 0\quad\mbox{when}\quad a < 1$.

Comment: @FelixMarin you mean $P'(a)=2f(a)/a^2<1$?

Comment: @FelixMarin How can the integral of a non-negative function be negative?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I guess we are using different definitions. My function is the original one in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{\on{E}\ \mbox{and}\ \on{K}}$ are the *Complete Elliptic Integral* and the *Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind*, respectively.
\begin{align}
& \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\on{P}\pars{a}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{4\on{E}\pars{1 - a^{4}} \over a^{2}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\on{P}'\pars{a}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{4 \over a^{2}\pars{a^{4} - 1}}\ \times}
\\ &&
\ds{\bracks{\pars{1 + a^{4}}\on{E}\pars{1 - a^{4}} -2a^{4}\on{K}\pars{1 - a^{4}}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{P}\pars{a}\ \mbox{and}\
\on{P}'\pars{a}}$ pictures, respectively:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is $f(a)$?

Comment: I think this is not the same function I considered in my answer.

Comment: @enzotib It’s, indeed, $P(a)$ as given in the original post. I already changed it in my answer. Sorry about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I used the original one as given in the post. Thanks.